# Netsuite Customized Income Statement timing out

Tags: netsuite

I'm experiencing issues when running an existing customized income statement that I've been using for years.  I run the report and then after a few minutes I am prompted to confirm whether I want to continue running the report in thr background and will be notified once its completed.  The issue is that it gets hung up and never completes and support has no idea why.  I'm at a loss, has anyone experienced this issue before and came up with a solution?

I'm not confident that support can figure out the issue, they're supposedly looking into it.  Initially, they questioned why I can't just use the standard income statement.  It's because the customized version saves me time alot of time and has always worked previously, it was created for a reason.

Thanks so much!!